# my plot picture have two xticks and two yticks by using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, datetime

the code is so simple, but there are two xticks and two yticks. it's so strange!

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,12))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)
ax1.plot(data['timestamp'], data['value'], 'r', label='value')
ax1.set_xlabel('date', fontsize=16)
ax1.set_ylabel('profit', fontsize=16)
ax1.legend(loc='upper left')
ax1.grid(True)
```

the data value is below:

```
    0   2010-01-04
    1   2010-01-04
    2   2010-03-08
    3   2010-07-05
    4   2010-11-04
Name: timestamp, dtype: datetime64[ns]

    0    1.037868
    1    1.085912
    2    1.092537
    3    1.077828
    4    1.160641
```

plot:
[image]

I just want the data['timestamp'] and data['value'] show on the picture.

I have tried to add the code below, but the result is the same.

```
ax1.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
ax1.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.YearLocator())
ax1.xaxis.set_minor_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
```

I have get the x-tick and y-ticks, the result as below, there are not any value like 0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0 in the result.
[14610. 14641. 14669. 14700. 14730. 14761. 14791. 14822. 14853. 14883. 14914.]
[1.02 1.04 1.06 1.08 1.1  1.12 1.14 1.16 1.18]

Comment: Hii, I took your timestamp and value in lists and tried to replicate your output. Surprisingly, I am not getting any error and the plot looks perfect just like yours but without any error.

Comment: It looks like you are creating two axes on top of each other.  Could you create a full example that reproduces your problem? Are you sure you aren't calling `fig.add_subplot` or some similar function (e.g. `plt.axes()`) a second time?

Comment: I'm sorry the missing code is " plt.title("value today") ". If I delete this code everything is right, but I don't know why?